# populate data from database using php ajax val()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i got something weird in my code. honestly, i got this from someone and i try to adapt it for my needs. So the problem is when i click fetch button, the data is not display. can any body here tell me what is wrong with the code?
Any related answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

and here are my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myrequest(e) {
        var name = $('.username').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/spdb/debug/autofill.php", /* online, change this to your real url */
            data: {
                username: name
            },
 
            success: function( responseObject ) {
                alert('success');
                $('#posts').val(responseObject.level);
                $('#joindate').val(responseObject.last_login);
                
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    }
    
    $('#fetchFields').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myrequest();
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="?act=proc">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form</legend>
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> 
                <button id="fetchFields">fetch</button>
                <label for="posts">Posts: </label>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="posts" id="posts">
                <label for="joindate">Joindate: </label>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="joindate" id="joindate">
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitBtn"></p>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the PHP code :

```
$return = mysqli_query($konek, "SELECT * FROM tb_auth WHERE username ='admin' LIMIT 1");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($return);
$formattedData = json_encode($rows);
print $formattedData;`
```

here are the result from PHP Code :

```
{
    "0":"1",
    "id_auth":"1",
    "1":"TRC-US001",
    "auth_code":"TRC-US001",
    "2":"admin",
    "username":"admin",
    "3":"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99",
    "password":"5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99",
    "4":"1",
    "level":"1",
    "5":"2018-07-05 13:55:19.200878",
    "last_login":"2018-07-05 13:55:19.200878",
    "6":"1",
    "status":"1"
}
```

this is the picture : 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSl9G.png)

Comment: Is the url in the ajax correct? I am just asking, because of the comment behind it.

Comment: yes, that's the correct URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can help you

first we need to do some modification on html, and php code :

```
<!-- doctype is mandatory -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- language en -->
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- title also is mandatory -->
        <title>tilte of your project</title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="?act=proc">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Form</legend>
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"> 
                <button id="fetchFields">fetch</button>
                <label for="posts">Posts: </label>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="posts" id="posts">
                <label for="joindate">Joindate: </label>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="joindate" id="joindate">
                <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitBtn"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <!-- put all your javascript before the end of the body -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function myrequest(e) {
                    // use $('#username') to select by id instead of $('.username') used to select by class
                    var name = $('#username').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost/spdb/debug/autofill.php", /* online, change this to your real url */
                        data: {
                            username: name
                        },
                        dataType: 'json', /* this is not mandatory */
                        success: function( responseObject ) {
                            console.log('success');
                            $('#posts').val(responseObject.level);
                            $('#joindate').val(responseObject.last_login);

                        },
                        failure: function() {
                            alert('fail');
                        }
                    });
                }

                $('#fetchFields').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    myrequest();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

php code :

```
// this line is very important, by using this line
// the browser can recognize that the data sent from
// the server as a json object.
header("Content-type: application/json");

$formattedData  = [];

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username       = trim($_GET['username']);
    // to be sure that the username is not empty
    if(empty($username)) {
        print json_encode($formattedData);
        exit;
    }
    $konek          = mysqli_connect($sql_db_host, $sql_db_user, $sql_db_pass, $sql_db_name, 3306);
    $return         = mysqli_query($konek, "SELECT * FROM tb_auth WHERE username = '" . $username . "' LIMIT 1");
    // use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array
    // $rows           = mysqli_fetch_array($return);
    $rows           = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return);
    $formattedData  = json_encode($rows);
    // very important every connection created need to be closed
    mysqli_close($konek);
}
print $formattedData;
```

Comment: OMG thats 100% work, dude. JESUS. Thank you very much @doset thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In your html code, there is an input with an id `username`. In Javascript, search for this line of code `var name = $('.username').val();`. Change `.` to `#`. It should be `var name = $('#username').val();`.

`.username` is for any tag that have a class `username`.

`#username` will search for a tag that have an id `username`.

Comment: still not work, bro. Still not display the data in <input id="post"> and <input id="joindate">.  i have a feel that the problem is in responseObject, but i don't know what is wrong with this function.

Comment: yes, the alert show up. but not return the value. if you change this   $('#posts').val(responseObject.level); into   $('#posts').val('my value'); , you will know the different

Comment: try to open the url in your ajax on web browser. You can see the result.

Comment: its work, i dont know. but that return a json data. what is the problem? is that the problem?

Comment: Put that result on your question. Maybe I can help with that.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I thought you code is okay after seeing the result. Try changing the level and last_login into number. Like `responseObject[4]`

Comment: maybe you can try in your local using your own data for the best result.

Comment: its solved bro. thanks for your effort. i appreciated that.

Answer (score 0):

try to parse responseObject to json using

responseObject=JSON.parse(responseObject);

in you success function

Comment: which part that i have to change bro?

Comment: @haldinfoods  in your success function before using responseObject

Comment: hey bro, after i follow your answer, the result display like a just post in my question. please take a look

Comment: its solved bro. thanks for your effort. i appreciated that.

Comment: your problem is that you are receiving data as string/text format, and try to using it as java script object ,before using response as object you should parse it to json object,that's it,can you specify what error shown in you browser console?